# How to get one by one value from result of group_concat mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I got result using `group_concat`

Example result is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(customerid) FROM customers;
```

output is:

```
121,123,60,24,56,78,45,67,143,etc
```

Based on customerid now I want to update some details in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `group_concat()`.  Use a subquery or `join`.  Something like this:

```
update othertable
    set col = value
    where customerid in (select customerid from customers);
```

Comment: no sir my actual query as follows ..UPDATE fcl_bl SET received_master='Yes' WHERE file_number IN
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(module_ref_id SEPARATOR ';') FROM notes WHERE module_id = 'file' AND note_desc LIKE '%(Received SSL Master -> Yes to No)%') AND received_master='No' ;

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do a JOIN between the tables rather than use a subquery:-

```
UPDATE fcl_bl a
INNER JOIN notes b
ON a.file_number = b.module_ref_id
AND b.module_id = 'file' 
AND b.note_desc LIKE '%(Received SSL Master -> Yes to No)%'
SET a.received_master='Yes' 
WHERE received_master='No'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.your query is executed.but it does not affect any rows in fcl_bl table.

Comment: Can you post the table declarations and a couple of example lines please?